# Enter data into a website's input bar using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to create a program that will input data into an input bar on a website. I have done some research and it looks like most use CURL to achieve this. I am new to CURL. So far, I coded a simple program that transcribes the website to my local host.

The input bar I am trying to enter data into is titled "Decode Your Vehicle Identification Number". Ideally, I want to enter a vehicle's VIN number into this, have the program submit it, then capture all the vehicle's data.

Here is my code thus far:

```
<?php

 // init the resource
 $ch = curl_init();

 // set a single option...
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.dmv.org/vehicle-history/vin-decoder.php');

 // execute
 $output = curl_exec($ch);

 // free
 curl_close($ch);

 print_r($output);

?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not so sure CURL can be used to do this.  Sounds like you want to automate the browser... maybe try [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need CURL for this, since the form works with a GET request. And the output is nicely formatted JSON. You can just use `file_get_contents()` like this:

```
$vin = '...';
$json = file_get_contents(
    'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevinextended/' . $vin . '?format=json'
);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: this works well and is far easier than some CURL methods I saw. How did you get the link?

Comment: Opened the site in a browser, opened the browser's network debug panel, submitted the form, looked at what the browser submitted.

Comment: Understood. What about for a site like this: https://www.toyota.com/owners/vehicle-specification. I can't find what the browser submitted like I can with the other site.

Comment: It's the same process. Developer Tools -> Network tab, submit the form, look for a new request to appear.

Comment: I've tried, it seems like Toyota might encrypt the request. Definitely not as straightforward as finding the first request through the debug panel.

Comment: warning, this approach requires `allow_url_fopen=true` in php.ini, also it does not support compression, and it ignores the Content-Length header, and simply keeps downloading until the socket is closed by the remote server, so this approach is slower than curl, sometimes much slower.

Comment: warning, you're not encoding $vin , the code would probably fail for a $vin containing special characters like `æ  ø å / : ; %`  - the correct code would probably be `decodevinextended/' . urlencode($vin) . '?format=json'`

Comment: @hanshenrik VINs contain only digits and uppercase letters, no encoding required.

Comment: @mugelloblue It's not encrypted, I'm looking right at it. Make sure you click the "Preserve Log" checkbox. (Once the browser submits the form and renders the next page, it clears the network tab otherwise.) Also check the boxes to show you only "Doc" and "XHR" type requests, so you don't have to wade through all the images, JS, and CSS.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Still having issues with my browser for some reason. Can you edit your answer to accommodate the toyota.com/owners/vehicle-specification link? That would help me out a lot.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Look at the request sent to Toyota in the browser's network panel; it is something like: https://www.toyota.com/services/public/u/vehicle/JTMZF4DV5AD025666?nvsCheck=false&cacheBuster=1544306992573. The two additional parameters in the query string I suspect are some kind of security (pure speculation of course, probably marketing not security). If you send that request, it returns a 403 Forbidden page